# Deployment of c# app with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, deployment, sql-server-express

I need your help because I've searched and read many sources but I'm really confused, and I hope you help me.

I have an application created in VS 2012 Ultimate with a SQL Server Express database, and I need to install it on the client's machine. As I'm a beginner and this is my first app, I find it really hard to install it.

I tried publishing the app but changes are not saved in the db.

Can someone please guide how to install the app on the client machine? What are the pre-requisites to be installed on the client machine other than .Net framework?

Comment: Can you post more information about your solution structure, and exactly what problems you are having with the deployment?

Comment: it's a simple windows form application with basic read/write fxns, and I need to install the app for the client to use it. I tried using the publish option in vs but it didn't work on the client machine.
Any ideas how to install it correctly on the client machine

Comment: Have you tried installing SQL server express on the client machine? You can download the SSE executables here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299 or if you are trying to create an installer with ClickOnce you can read this tutorial https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manisblog/2008/12/22/how-to-deploy-sql-server-2008-express-as-a-prerequisite-with-clickonce/

Comment: @zozi: `"but it didn't work on the client machine"` - Can you be more specific?  *What* "didn't work"?  How exactly did it fail?

Comment: @David the app ran and the forms showed but any changes to the db were not saved. I guess when I chose publish app and got the .exe file the db where not included in the setup, right??

Comment: @zozi: Is the connection string in the app.config correct?  Maybe it's saving to a different database than the one you're looking at?  If there's an error saving the data then the application would be aware of that (such as not being able to actually connect to the target database), but nobody here can know how your code is actually handling such an error because nobody here can see the relevant code.

Comment: @david should I install the sql server express to the client machine? Because I haven't install it. Sry but I'm really new to this

Comment: Well, you can think, or? Because whether or not you install SQL Express on the client machines depends on how you were thinking when you were programming. Do the clients maintain their own database locally, or connect to a server? How you think we should know? YOU came up with the concept for YOUR program.

Comment: @TomTom sry for asking these questions but I'm new to this. I came up with this method can you check it for me. I installed the sql server express and .net framework on the client pc and I was took the [appname].exe and app.config and tried to test them on my PC before testing them on the client but the app didn't even start. Are these files enough or I'm missing